# iptables, are all ports open? how do i remove line?

Tags: iptables, firewall, unix

it´ been an long time i configured my firewall and now i see there might be an error, heres the INPUT part of iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
fail2ban-SSH  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/NONE
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:!FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN state NEW
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:urd
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:pop3
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:pop3s
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:imap
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:imaps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh
```

do you see the line,

`ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere`

without any parameters, does this mean all Ports are open? how do i change this line ?

Comment: You might want to add which distribution you are using, some distributions use management tools for the firewall that override your changes on the next reboot.

Comment: i´m running CentOs 6.8 Final and i manually configured this with iptables

Answer (score 1):

If you are manually managing `iptables`, you need to write the rules to a file using [`iptables-save(8)`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables-save):

```
# iptables-save > /tmp/iptables.txt
```

Edit the rules as you please, then restore the set with [`iptables-restore(8)`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables-restore):

```
# iptables-restore /tmp/iptables.txt
```

Check the `iptables` documentation (`apropos iptables`) and online blog posts about configuring a stateful firewall with `iptables`.
E.g. ['Towards the perfect ruleset'](http://inai.de/documents/Perfect_Ruleset.pdf), by Jan Engelhardt.

Answer (score 1):

if you run :

```
iptables -L --line-numbers
```

you will have a line number reference:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    fail2ban-SSH  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh
3    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
4    DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/NONE
5    DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:!FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN state NEW
6    DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG
7    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
8    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http
9    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https
[...]
```

and then you can run

```
iptables -D INPUT 7
```

Comment: made it like that, nevertheless the rule seemed to be necessary so i needed to add it afterwards, so maybe you can explan why this does this not open all ports and seems to be required for port 80 to work?

Comment: The iptables -L output does not give enough informations to understand.

Comment: Sorry, I wrongly pressed enter. you should paste the output of 

    iptables -L -v

or 

    iptables-save

but maybe in another question, since the title would become misleading. And please accept my answer if it helped you :)